# Delete button not working in Lightning

Tags: lightning, community, controller-extension, form

I want to enable the button delete function, but not working. :(

see my abbreviated code.

Apex Class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean deleteCliente(Id lstClienteId) {
    Cliente__c n = [SELECT Id FROM Cliente__c WHERE Id = :lstClienteId];

    try{
        delete n;
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }

}
```

Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="ListOfCliente" type="Cliente__c[]" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadClientetList}" />


<form class="account-form" >
                        <input type="hidden" value="{!Cliente.Name}" class="account-name" />
                        <!-- Use a Lightning Base Component To display an icon next to the label -->
                        <lightning:button
                                          label="Delete"
                                          iconName="utility:delete"
                                          iconPosition="left"
                                          variant="destructive"
                                          type="submit"
                                          onclick="{!c.deleteCliente}"

                                          />
                    </form>
```

Controller:

[image]

Helper:

```
({

deleteSelected : function(component, event, deleteClienteIds) {
    var deleteClienteIds = component.get("v.Cliente.Id");        
    var action = component.get("c.deleteCliente");   

    action.setParams({
        "lstClienteId": deleteClienteIds
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();

    console.log("CHEGUEI AQUI");
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            if (response.getReturnValue() != '') {
                alert('The following error has occurred. while Delete record-->' + response.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.log('check it--> delete successful');
            }   

            // Refresh na Página 
               location.reload();
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

})

But,  it still does not delete the contact. seemingly all right with the code. I do not understand !!!   Thanks for help me

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="{!Cliente.Name}" class="account-name" /> Where you have defined the attribute called **Cliente**?

Comment: hi, thanks for helpe me. I put it but it did not work  see now
<aura:attribute name="Cliente" type="Cliente__c"/>

Answer (score 0):

- `deleteSelected` has three arguments but you are passing only two,
  `deleteSelected : function(component, event, deleteClienteIds) { ... }`. `deleteClienteIds` is missing.
- You need to pass Id of the `Cliente__c` object to this method, then
  it should work.
- Not sure where is `Cliente` is defined, I am assuming you have, so you should pass its id, not name from markup. See below markup:

`<input type="hidden" value="{!Cliente.Id}" class="account-name" />`

Comment: hi, thanks for helpe me.
So, See my code now 

component:
<aura:attribute name="Cliente" type="Cliente__c"/> {...} <input type="hidden" value="{!Cliente.Id}" class="account-name" />
Controller: helper.deleteSelected(component, event, helper);      

Helper: deleteSelected : function(component, event) { var currentRecordId = component.get("v.Cliente.Id"); var action = component.get("c.deleteCliente");        
        action.setParams({ "lstClienteId": currentRecordId });

Comment: @JoanesCavalcanti can you please update the code in the question itself? It is very hard to read it here in comments. Thanks.

Comment: ok, Thanks, you will my complete code in https://bit.ly/2vignOy  (bitbucket)

Comment: change line 111 to `helper.deleteSelected(component, event, nomeContato);` change line 133 to `deleteSelected : function(component, event,currentRecordId ){` and delete line 134,

Comment: @JoanesCavalcanti Please find the working code here, it is implemented for an account object [repo link](https://gitlab.com/rahulgawale/account-delete-lightning-component)

Comment: thanks raul very much,you were amazing !!! keep being like this :)